# add primefaces mobile to project

Tags: jsf, primefaces-mobile

i made this jsf page with primefaces 5.2 and it works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">

<f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />

<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>

    <pm:page id="first">
        <pm:header title="Page 1"></pm:header>

        <pm:content>
            <p>Multiple pages</p>

            <h:form>
                <p:button outcome="pm:second?transition=flip" value="Go Button" />
            </h:form>
        </pm:content>


    </pm:page>

    <pm:page id="second">
        <pm:header title="Page 2"></pm:header>

        <pm:content>
            <p>Page 2 content.</p>
        </pm:content>

        <h:form>
            <p:button outcome="pm:first?transition=slidefade" value="Go Button" />
        </h:form>
    </pm:page>

</h:body>

</html>
```

primefaces version on my project is 4 and i cant change it, Apparently it hasnt mobile version on it

so i downloaded primefaces mobile from [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces-mobile/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT) and added to project,but i get this error

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/hl/nursing/patientdocserviceform.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.write(CoyoteWriter.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.write(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.write(HtmlResponseWriter.java:717)
    at org.primefaces.mobile.component.page.PageRenderer.encodeBegin(PageRenderer.java:64)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.doFilter(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:121)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

i added code to faces-config,changed mobile version but none of them didnt work
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: added them @Kukeltje

Comment: The f:view should be around your page, not as an empty 'metatag' like tag